# Are non indian sims work in this mobile?

Tags: sim-card

I recently my Indian fb friend bought a Samsung F41 mobile online. On the package seal, it's written "Indian SIM Cards only".

Are non indian sims work in this mobile?

Answer (score 1):

The restriction only affect users the first time they activate the phone. In short, just for the first time you'll have to use an Indian sim and afterwards you can use any sim card from any part of the world.

Source - [Samsung: We don’t region-lock our phones (apart from when you first activate them)](https://gigaom.com/2013/09/27/samsung-region-locks-for-our-galaxy-smartphones-only-apply-the-first-time-you-insert-the-sim/)